# Trying to get the date payment was sent using Stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Im trying to console.log the date the payment was sent using token.create but it returns undefined. I was wondering how I could get the date created.

```
app.post('/payments.html', function(req, res) {
    var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express

// Create a charge: this will charge the user's card
    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 20000, // Amount in cents
        currency: "usd",
        source: token,
        description: "Example charge"
    }, function(err, charge) {
            if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
                 // The card has been declined
             }
    });

    console.log(charge.amount);
    stripe.customers.create({
        description: 'customer for..',
        source: token
    }), function(err, customer){
        console.log("error in creating customer" + err);
    }
    console.log(token.created);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/payments.html');

    });
```

Here is the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            // Fill in your publishable key
            Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_SkainfjXuZvik6J2Sg5praOz');

            var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
              var $form = $('#payment-form');

              if (response.error) {
                // Show the errors on the form
                $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                // token contains id, last4, and card type
                var token = response.id;
                // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
                // and re-submit
                $form.get(0).submit();
            }
        };

        jQuery(function($) {
          $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
            var $form = $(this);

                // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
                $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

                Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

                // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
                return false;
            });
      });
        </script>
```

Here is the form where you enter your payment details

```
 <form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                  <span style="color:red;"class="payment-errors"></span>
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                    <span>Name</span>
                     <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="name">
                    </label>
                    <label>
                    <span>Zip Code</span>
                     <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="address_zip">
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
                  </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
                    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
                </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
                </label>
            </div>


          <div class="form-row">
            <label>
              <span>CVC</span>
              <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
          </label>
      </div>


      <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are posting the entire token object and not just the token id.

Comment: Yeah, here's the bit:

`var token = response.id;`

You can instead send the whole token object back.  You'll need to stringify it to add it to the form or post via ajax instead.

You'll also need to modify your backend code to just grab the id from the token for the charge.